# Swift: Silence "Non-Sendable Notification? cannot cross actor boundary" warning

Tags: swift, actor, swift-concurrency

### Problem

I have a Mac app that needs to perform an action when the Mac sleeps. To do this, I'm using this "modern" approach to listen for the notification:

```swift
@MainActor
final class AppController: NSObject, ObservableObject
{
   var sleepTask: Task<Void, Never>? = nil

   override init()
   {
       sleepTask = Task { [weak self] in
          for await _ in NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.notifications(named: NSWorkspace.willSleepNotification) 
          {
              self?.doSomething()
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Xcode 15 beta 8 has introduced a new warning on the `for/await` call:

> Non-sendable type 'Notification?' returned by implicitly asynchronous call to nonisolated function cannot cross actor boundary
> 1. Generic enum 'Optional' does not conform to the 'Sendable' protocol (Swift.Optional)

[image]

But I'm not *using* the notification object at all; it's not crossing the actor boundary.

### Question:

How can I silence this warning? (Other than forcing `Optional` to conform to `@unchecked Sendable`).

Comment: I don’t even know where the optional came from! `.notifications` returns `NotificationCenter.Notifications`, whose `.Element` is the non-optional `Notification`.

Comment: @Sweeper - I'll update the example with less truncated code

Comment: Is this the real code? If this inherits from `NSObject` the compiler will complain about not overriding `init`.

Comment: @vadian - It is. In my actual app there is a parameter in init(), which I omitted here because it's not relevant. I'll add the override keyword for pedantic completeness.

Comment: And why do you run `doSomething` on another `MainActor` `Task` as the class (and also `doSomething`) runs on the main actor anyway?

Comment: I agree. The Task inside a Task is just wrong.

Comment: Also why are you saving off a reference to the task (`sleepTask`)? That seems like a waste.

Comment: @vadian - the inner Task block is a copy/paste oversight from a different context where dispatching to the main thread was needed. I’ll edit to remove; thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said:

> How can I silence this warning? (Other than forcing `Optional` to conform to `@unchecked Sendable`).

You can:

1. You can declare `Notification` to be `Sendable`. E.g.,

   ```swift
   extension Notification: @unchecked Sendable { }
   ```

   This is disquieting. It feels like this `struct` should be `Sendable`, but it’s not clear why it isn't. I don't know whether they just have not gotten around to it yet or whether there is something going on internally that prevents them from doing so.
2. You can also change your sequence to yield something other than a `Notification`:

   ```swift
   sleepTask = Task { [weak self] in
       let sequence = NSWorkspace
           .shared
           .notificationCenter
           .notifications(named: NSWorkspace.willSleepNotification)
           .map { _ in () }

       for await _ in sequence {
           self?.doSomething()
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: The `.map` is what we do in our app.

Comment: “It feels like this struct should be Sendable, but it’s not clear why it isn't.” I’m guessing it’s just a wrapper around a reference to an NSNotification.

Comment: Agreed. But why isn’t that `Sendable`, too? Does it have mutable state? Its exposed properties are all immutable…

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity: is option 1 the only route if I actually DO need to use the notification object?

Comment: No. If you “need” the notification object, it’s generally because you need to extract stuff from the `userInfo`. So I have `map` of the sequence in option 2 extract what I need. Option 1 is if you think (like I suspect) that the lack of `Sendable` for `Notification` is just a pre-Swift 6 preconcurrency oversight. As a general rule, marking something that is not `Sendable` as such is a very bad idea, but I personally suspect this `Notification` issue is just a temporary state of affairs, something that Apple is likely to fix before Swift 6 comes around.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know why the compiler is complaining that `Notification?` isn’t `Sendable` rather than just `Notification`?

Comment: I’d wager that it is because an asynchronous sequence has an iterator, which conforms to [`AsyncIteratorProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asynciteratorprotocol), which returns `Element?` (i.e., produces a series of elements, but emits `nil` when the sequence is done).

Answer (score 1):

This is not what you asked, but you don't need (and shouldn't use) a Task within a Task, and you don't need (and shouldn't use) a reference to your Task. The following will do what you want done:

```
@MainActor
final class AppController: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        Task { [weak self] in
            let center = NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter
            let willSleep = NSWorkspace.willSleepNotification
            for await _ in center.notifications(named: willSleep).map({ _ in }) {
                self?.doSomething()
            }
        }
    }
    func doSomething() {}
}
```

Properly speaking, you should also add a `break` that cancels the task just in case `self` (the AppController) goes out of existence. I take it that it will *not* go out of existence, but it is best to make a habit of doing things properly:

```
@MainActor
final class AppController: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        Task { [weak self] in
            let center = NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter
            let willSleep = NSWorkspace.willSleepNotification
            for await _ in center.notifications(named: willSleep).map({ _ in }) {
                guard let self else { break }
                doSomething()
            }
        }
    }
    func doSomething() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see first where your problem comes from.

1. `AsyncSequence` requires defining an iterator that has a `func next() async -> Notification?` method used by the runtime to know when to end the for loop. Thus, behind the scenes, the for loop behaves more like a while:

   ```swift
   var asyncIterator = NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.notifications(named: 
   NSWorkspace.willSleepNotification).makeAsyncIterator()
   while let notification = await asyncIterator.next() {
       self?.doSomething()
   }
   ```
2. The notifications are delivered on their own async execution context, while the task you create in `init` inherits the execution context, meaning it will execute on the main actor. This means the notification objects will have to be passed between different concurrent execution contexts, hence the warning.

Solutions to fix the warning have already been provided, but since I don't like to write an answer without also giving a possible solution, here is one from me: use a detached task.

```
sleepTask = Task.detached { [weak self] in
    for await _ in NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.notifications(named: NSWorkspace.willSleepNotification)
    {
        await self?.doSomething()
    }
}
```

A detached task doesn't inherit the current actor execution context, which means the for loop will run in the same execution context as the publisher of the notifications. But, this implies that:

1. in order to hop back on the main actor, you'll need to `await` the `doSomething` call. I don't see this as a problem, au-contraire, it might make things more obvious.
2. you'll need to make sure to cancel the task in the deinit of `AppController`, otherwise the for-loop will run indifinetely. But this is also the case with the "non-detached" task, any unstructured tasks you create will need to be "manually" cancelled, otherwise they will leak resources.